# Set communication between two web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have 2 web sites that are published on the same server.The first one was built using web forms and the second one (The CRM) was built using MVC. 
In the crm I have a web api controller that adds new order. The access to the controller is only granted for crms admins. Now I need to have the ability to call this controller and add new orer from the first site. I thought about couple of ways that it can be done and I can really use some help to decide what is the best option.

1.Create a wcf communication between them and wrap the controller this controller with intenal access only (From the same computer only)

2.Pass a pre defined token from first site to the crm.

3.Check in the crm controller if the request was made from the same server

4.Create using owin a self hosted web api in the crm , that listens to some localhost port.

5.Any other idea with explanation

Kind regards,

Tal Humy

Answer (score 0):

If they're on the same server, is there an exposed API to the classes themselves? Can you reference your MVC project from your web forms code? Doing this would flatten the communication layer so you wouldn't use up networking resources unnecessarily.

Comment: If you mean adding the mvc dll to the web form site , it will be very difficult to do. If you meant something else , I will be happy if you can explain.

Comment: I was thinking that if this is a situation where you have two interfaces to the same data, although they are different projects they are essentially the same application. If that's not the case, or if you're wanting to keep the two projects separate so they can be placed on separate servers, what I suggested wouldn't apply.
In a project that I worked on that had a similar breakdown, we opted to flatten the application and provide web service interfaces for third-party SOAP requests.